# Is it possible to use Leaflet.draw on a map in R?

Tags: polygon, r, leaflet, line, leaflet-draw

I want to develop an application where a user can draw a line, polygon etc...

I currently develop with R and leaflet package and I found that it is possible to work with [Leaflet.draw](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/) under JavaScript.

My question is, can I operate it under R?

Edit :

I copied in my Directory : [leaflet.draw.js,leaflet.draw.css,leaflet-draw-plugin.js](https://github.com/byzheng/leaflet/tree/5c207af4764dc83e1736e1e4dd8e88e9fca84856/inst/htmlwidgets)

plugin-draw.R

```
leafletDrawDependencies <- function() {
  list(
    htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "Leaflet.draw",
      "0.2.3",
      system.file("Users/insa/Documents/Biblio-graphique/toolbar/dist", package = "leaflet"),
      script = "leaflet.draw.js",
      stylesheet="leaflet.draw.css"
    ),
    htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "leaflet-draw-plugin",
      "0.0.1",
      system.file("Users/insa/Documents/Biblio-graphique/toolbar", package = "leaflet"),
      script = "leaflet-draw-plugin.js"
    )
  )
}


addDrawToolbar <- function(map,layerID="drawnItems",
                           group = layerID,
                           position = c('topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft',
                                        'bottomright'),
                           polyline=TRUE,polygon=TRUE,rectangle=TRUE,
                           circle=TRUE,marker=TRUE,edit=TRUE, remove=TRUE) {

  position = match.arg(position)
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, leafletDrawDependencies())
  map$drawToolbar<-T
  invokeMethod(map,getMapData(map),method =  'addDrawToolbar',layerID,group,position,
               polyline,polygon,rectangle,circle,marker,edit,remove)
}

drawPolylineOptions <- function(allowIntersection = TRUE,
                                drawError = list(color = "#b00b00", timeout = 2500),
                                guidelineDistance = 20,
                                shapeOptions = list(stroke = TRUE, color = '#f06eaa', weight = 4,
                                                    opacity = 0.5, fill = FALSE, clickable = TRUE
                                ), metric = TRUE, zIndexOffset = 2000, repeatMode = FALSE
) {
  list(
    allowIntersection = allowIntersection,
    drawError = drawError,
    guidelineDistance = guidelineDistance,
    shapeOptions = shapeOptions,
    metric = metric,
    zIndexOffset = zIndexOffset,
    repeatMode = repeatMode
  )
}


drawPolygonOptions <- function(allowIntersection = TRUE,
                               drawError = list(color = "#b00b00", timeout = 2500),
                               guidelineDistance = 20,
                               shapeOptions = list(stroke = TRUE, color = '#f06eaa', weight = 4,
                                                   opacity = 0.5, fill = TRUE, fillColor = NULL, fillOpacity = 0.2,
                                                   clickable = TRUE
                               ), metric = TRUE, zIndexOffset = 2000, repeatMode = FALSE, showArea = FALSE
) {
  if (isTRUE(showArea) && isTRUE(allowIntersection)) {
    warning("showArea = TRUE will be ignored because allowIntersection is TRUE")
  }

  list(
    allowIntersection = allowIntersection,
    drawError = drawError,
    guidelineDistance = guidelineDistance,
    shapeOptions = shapeOptions,
    metric = metric,
    zIndexOffset = zIndexOffset,
    repeatMode = repeatMode,
    showArea = showArea
  )
}

#' @rdname drawPolylineOptions
#' @export
drawRectangleOptions <- function(shapeOptions = list(
  stroke = TRUE, color = '#f06eaa', weight = 4, opacity = 0.5,
  fill = TRUE, fillColor = NULL, fillOpacity = 0.2, clickable = TRUE),
  metric = TRUE, repeatMode = FALSE) {

  list(
    shapeOptions = shapeOptions,
    metric = metric,
    repeatMode = repeatMode
  )
}

#' @rdname drawPolylineOptions
#' @param showRadius whether to show the radius of the drawn circle
#' @export
drawCircleOptions <- function(shapeOptions = list(
  stroke = TRUE, color = '#f06eaa', weight = 4, opacity = 0.5,
  fill = TRUE, fillColor = NULL, fillOpacity = 0.2, clickable = TRUE),
  showRadius = TRUE, metric = TRUE, repeatMode = FALSE) {

  list(
    shapeOptions = shapeOptions,
    showRadius = showRadius,
    metric = metric,
    repeatMode = repeatMode
  )
}

#' @rdname drawPolylineOptions
#'
#' @param icon a custom icon, as created by \code{\link{makeIcon}}
#'
#' @export
drawMarkerOptions <- function(icon = NULL, zIndexOffset = 2000,
                              repeatMode = FALSE) {

  if (!is.null(icon)) {
    if (!inherits(icon, "leaflet_icon")) {
      stop("Icon must be created using the makeIcon() function")
    }
    icon$iconUrl <- b64EncodePackedIcons(packStrings(icon$iconUrl))$data
    icon$iconRetinaUrl <- b64EncodePackedIcons(packStrings(icon$iconRetinaUrl))$data
    icon$iconShadowUrl <- b64EncodePackedIcons(packStrings(icon$iconShadowUrl))$data
    icon$iconShadowRetinaUrl <- b64EncodePackedIcons(packStrings(icon$iconShadowRetinaUrl))$data
  }

  filterNULL(list(icon = icon, zIndexOffset = zIndexOffset, repeatMode = repeatMode))
}

#' @describeIn addDrawToolbar
#' @export
removeDrawToolbar <- function(map){
  invokeMethod(map,getMapData(map),method =  'removeDrawToolbar')
}


map <- addTiles(leaflet())
map <- addDrawToolbar(map)
map
```

but the toolbar is not displayed, what's missing?

[image]

Comment: Then what do you want to do once they've drawn? Get that info back into R? That's another problem....

Comment: for now just draw as toolbar

Comment: Check out this post -- it might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976414/drawing-multiple-polygons-with-leaflet-in-shiny

Comment: Any progress on this question? I'm trying to incorporate the same thing into my map now and it's not working.

Comment: http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-draw

Answer (score 4):

In short, Yes you can. You can find some good examples of [tutorials](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-leaflet-package-for-online-mapping-in-r/) as well as reading up on "Leaflet for R" using RStudio [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), offering the following features:

> ```
> Interactive panning/zooming
> Compose maps using arbitrary combinations of:
>     Map tiles
>     Markers
>     Polygons
>     Lines
>     Popups
>     GeoJSON
> ```

```
Create maps right from the R console or RStudio
Embed maps in knitr/R Markdown documents and Shiny apps
Easily render Spatial objects from the sp package, 
or data frames with latitude/longitude columns
Use map bounds and mouse events to drive Shiny logic
```

Comment: But I'm not sure its trivial to include a Leaflet plugin to a leaflet map made with the R leaflet package. There's a couple of examples but the plugins need to be integrated into the package code itself, so that the generated leaflet map uses the plugin.

Comment: Yes, I found this program https://github.com/byzheng/leaflet/blob/5c207af4764dc83e1736e1e4dd8e88e9fca84856/R/plugin-draw.R  with plugin that I try followed but it does not work for me, I can show you what I did?

Comment: Update your question with would you have tried already.

Answer (score 2):

To use leaflet.draw (and numerous other leaflet plugins) in R, try https://github.com/RCura/leaflet.extras.

Comment: As of January 2022, the R package `leaflet.extras` is abandoned (see [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras) and considered a potential security risk.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem on this is that in the `addDrawToolbar` command, you have `position` equal to: `c('topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright')`.  You need to pick one of these, like `position = 'topright'`.